# Accessing the position of the widget in device

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I want to require the imageview position from the device’s inside. but each time it gives back the 0. I have used this codes to do it:

```
                tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            tv1.setText("Accessing the position of the widget in device");
            Rect rectf = new Rect();
            tv1.getLocalVisibleRect(rectf);
            System.out.println("top" + rectf.top );
            System.out.println("Left:" + rectf.left);
            System.out.println("Right:" + rectf.right);
            System.out.println("Bottom:" + rectf.bottom);
```

**output :**

```
 10-12 05:42:55.101: I/System.out(31578): top:0
 10-12 05:42:55.101: I/System.out(31578): Left:0
 10-12 05:42:55.101: I/System.out(31578): Right:0
 10-12 05:42:55.101: I/System.out(31578): Bottom:0
```

Answer (score 1):

Where did you add this code? Android must have done the layout step before it can give you useful information about the positions of elements on the screen.

If your code is in `onCreate()` it is too early. `onResume()` is probably a better place.